# How to send a command and get the result ? API Python/C - PyRun_String

Tags: python-c-api, python-3.9

I would like to send a command to the interpreter and get the return of this command.

I'm actually using `PyRun_String` and it's working greatly but I have to pass in args `Py_single_input` if I want to init a variable like `a = 10`then I get `none`.
If I want to send `a` I have to put `Py_eval_input` in args then I get `10`.

So my problem is how I can merge `Py_single_input` and `Py_eval_input` to use this both fonction in a same function.

or

Is there another function other than `Pyrun_String`?

Comment: But `a=10` _doesn't have a value_ because it is a statement but not an expression. What result would you expect from `a, b = 1, 2`? Or `a[0] = 10`? This is why you can't do `if a=10:` in Python

Comment: Thanks but I know that. I wonder I can find a solution to merge both. If I send ```a```, the command know is an expression but if I send ```a = 10```, the command know is a statement. I imagine if it was possible, there wouldn't be that.